# What are the specifics of the Summoner's eidolon summoning ritual?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, summoner

The [summoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner) class casts a one minute ritual to call forth their Eidolon.  [From the PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner#TOC-Eidolon):

> A summoner can summon his eidolon in a ritual that takes 1 minute to perform.

Have Paizo ever stated anything official about what the ritual entails, or what the summoner can or can't do during that ritual?

Does it take full concentration? Can the summoner take 5 foot steps, move actions, anything?  Concentration checks needed?

Most of the discussion forums I've read just say "GM fiat," which is fine, but I'd love to know if there was anything official.

Comment: I've removed the [rules-as-written] tag from this question, since it would seem you'd find developer commentary acceptable too, but that doesn't generally fall under the umbrella of [rules-as-written]. Rest assured that on the basis you're requesting official commentary, answers saying "here's what I think it means" are going to be downvoted as unhelpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While there's nothing that specifically calls out the Summoner's Eidolon ritual, I'm going to use the rules for [casting time](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Casting-Time):

> A spell that takes 1 minute to cast comes into effect just before your turn 1 minute later (**and for each of those 10 rounds, you are casting a spell as a full-round action**, just as noted above for 1-round casting times). These actions must be consecutive and uninterrupted, or the spell automatically fails. **Emphasis mine**

The rules for a [full-round action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Full-Round-Actions) state:

> A full-round action requires an entire round to complete. Thus, it can't be coupled with a standard or a move action, though if it does not involve moving any distance, you can take a 5-foot step.

You must also maintain [concentration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Concentration) for the entire duration (10 rounds for a 1 minute spell) of the casting:

> When you begin a spell that takes 1 round or longer to cast, you must continue the invocations, gestures, and concentration from 1 round to just before your turn in the next round (at least). If you lose concentration after starting the spell and before it is complete, you lose the spell.

So you may make a 5-foot step every round, but injury, violent motion and other dangers force concentration checks and, if you miss your roll, you must restart the ritual.

Comment: Accepting this as solution.  Thanks @jason .  Strictly speaking, it isn't a spell, but a "ritual," but I agree it is certainly a form of magic casting time, so those rules seem reasonable to apply. Thanks for the find.

Comment: @JesseM No problem. I simply compare it to spells like [Augury](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/augury). Spells don't have a ritual tag like in some systems, but some can certainly be said to be rituals, so I interpret it vice versa as well. :)